# Can npm devDependencies be used in production?

Tags: javascript, npm

One of our products at work is a JS SDK that our clients can install and use with `npm install ...`. I was going through the `package.json` file and found that a package, `socket.io-client` was installed as a `devDependency`. But the SDK is using `socket.io` for an integral part of its working, and it obviously it's working for our clients. So, why is it working? Since, going by the documentation, `devDependencies` should not be installed when using `npm install`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what's happening here. So when you do `npm install`, npm will install all the dependencies, both devDependencies and regular dependencies. If you don't want to install devDependencies, use the `--production` flag with `npm install`.